# Is there a colour standard for mains 'signal' wiring?

Tags: mains, wiring, compliance, colour-coding, chassis

Hello I am currently wiring a mains powered chassis. I have relays which use mains voltage levels for controlling other mains voltage relays. I would like to differentiate between the signals by using striped brown-red, brown-blue cabling etc.

This has to go through compliance testing. Do all 'live' mains voltages need to be coloured solid brown?

***Edit:*** This is currently a product destined for the EU market.

Comment: Placing wire number marker on the wires is a good idea

Comment: It would be helpful for you to mention your locale, as this deals with regulations that vary between jurisdictions. I'm assuming EU due to the mention of brown being live, but more specific location--e.g., which country--may be needed.

Answer (score 1):

No it varies by country and voltage:

[image]

Wiring Color Codes Infographic. Released under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License